# Unwanted tags on migrated questions cannot be removed

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, tags, migrated-questions

I took it upon myself to remove the few instances of the [discipline](/questions/tagged/discipline) tag on Stack Overflow.

However [there's one left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651551/blank-screen-if-kids-yell-too-much?noredirect=1) that seems to be un-removable since it was migrated. The copy that remains on SO is locked and uneditable.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is intentional or how much of a problem this is, but IMO this tag shouldn't exist. It still comes up in the auto-suggest:

[image]

I'm not sure what the best approach to this pretty small problem is, but I wanted to bring it up. It seems reasonable that off-topic (migrated) questions are likely to have unusual tags, and I don't think we want to immortalize them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stubs for migrated questions get auto-deleted in a month. So I don't see that it will be a problem.

If that is indeed the last question that has the tag, the tag will die soon after the stub gets deleted.

Comment: However, in that month the tag can be used on other questions stopping it actually being removed after that time.

Comment: I think that's a pretty rare scenario. Just have a mod nuke the tag and/or the stub.

Comment: I didn't even realize that question was only a few weeks old! I always see heavily upvoted CW questions and just assume they're from the olden days (although I don't think this would have prevented me asking about this, as I didn't know about the stub auto-delete). Thanks, this solves it in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

These aren't the tags you're looking for...

Comment: Meta can have a strong influence on the weak-minded. You
will find it a powerful ally.

Comment: Stack Overflow lacks [discipline].

Comment: In all seriousness, it seems like a non-issue in light of Mystical's response, do you agree?